# Fluentd: How to use env variable in record config

Tags: fluentd, fluent-design

I have a container which has a env variable set:

```
env['POD_NAME'] = 'some-pod-name'
```

Now, I want to use it while setting a json object in record:

```
<parse>
     @type openmetrics
     <record>
       namespace ns1
       resourceGroup rg1
       dimensions {"a": "1234", "b": "xyz", "node": "#{ENV['POD_NAME']}"}
    </record> 
</parse>
```

Comment: Is it not working? Please add link of the plugin that you're using. Thanks!